# runtime error: No instance for (Stacked Int) arising from a use of ‘/+/’

Tags: class, haskell, instance, newtype

I wrote a simple type: `Stack`  and a class type `Stacked` with instance for two operations "plus" & "minus". It compiled but run time produce error as on the title.
Code is:

```
newtype Stack a = Stack a deriving (Show)

class Stacked a  where 
    (/+/) :: a -> Stack [a] -> Stack [a]
    (/-/) :: Stack [a] -> Stack [a]

instance Stacked (Stack a) where
    (/+/) x (Stack xs) = Stack (x:xs) 
    (/-/) (Stack xs) = Stack (tail xs)
```

I have tried use (Stacked a) => ... in the instance, but no result.
What i have made wrong?

PS. I know i have to check for [] but in this case it is not important  IMHO

Comment: The type signature of `(/+/)` is `(/+/) :: a -> Stack [a] -> Stack [a]`, hence for your instance `Stacked Stack a`, it means `(/+/)` has type `Stack a -> Stack [Stack a] -> Stack [Stack a]`. You probably want to make a class `class Stacked s` with `(/+/) :: a -> s a -> s a` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at how `Foldable` is defined and instantiated, you probably want to code it like

```hs
class Stacked a  where 
    (/+/) :: x -> a x -> a x
    pop :: a x -> a x

instance Stacked Stack where
    (/+/) x (Stack xs) = Stack (x:xs) 
    pop (Stack []) = Stack []
    pop (Stack xs) = Stack (tail xs)
```

this way the `Stacked` type class can be implemented for any type and is not depended on the type `Stack`.

Also through defining `Stack` as

```
newtype Stack a = Stack [a] deriving (Show)
```

we can use it simply by writing `Stack Int` and not `Stack [Int]`, this way the implementation of `Stack` (that it uses a list internally) is hidden from the user.

The use of an operator for an unary function is not so good I would just use a normal function.

And you definitly should capture the case of the empty list and probably should add a function like `isEmpty` to the type-class.